# Error Logs in Newly setup Working Environment

Tags: flutter

After setting up my new laptop to work with VS Code and flutter, I noticed that while running an app, there is a big Error Log in the terminal. Is there any way of getting rid of this?

[image: See here the spam]

It's working perfectly in other system. Therefore, I don't think it has something to do with my code.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! This is not spam, this is an error log. If you scroll up to #1 and a few lines before, you'll see what the error says, maybe you can find out why this happens only in one computer.

Comment: +1 For George's answer, also, it can be that different versions of Flutter generate different error logs, hence the differences. Are the Flutter versions on your other laptops older by chance?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the error's were indeed caused by different versions of flutter!